# How to error check for more than a certain amount of Command Parameters

Tags: c#, error-handling, command-line-arguments

I'm not quite sure how to google search this or put it into one sentence but here is my scenario.

I am creating a simple program  in C# that one feature of it is to take command parameters and to get a directory from a certain command parameter and an output in another command parameter. I have 2 parameters that the first one is InputPath and the 2nd is Output path. Pretty basic.

I'm doing error checking to see if the directorys they placed are valid using

```
if(Directory.Exists(args[0])&Directory.Exists(args[1]))
{
    GenManifest(args[0], args[1]);
}
```

*My question is how can I make it so if they place more than 2 command parameters that I can place an error like follows*

```
MessageBox.Show("Please only insert 2 arguements","Error");
```

I also have a simple

```
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid arguement format","Error");
}
```

to cover the majority of all other errors.

I'm also thinking of other ways to error check my code but for now i want the directories to be valid and to have the proper amount of arguements.

Thank you!

Daniel Sterba

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just check the length of the args array:

```
if (args.Length != 2)
{
    // Display error
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (args.Length != 2)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please only insert 2 arguements","Error");
}
```

Also you should change `&` to `&&` so:

```
if (Directory.Exists(args[0]) && Directory.Exists(args[1]))
{
    GenManifest(args[0], args[1]);
}
```

Here if the first condition returns false the second condition will be ignored.

Comment: && is the correct format when ensuring that code requires two boolean results to be true.

Comment: Yes that is true. but note that `&` in C# can be used here but the _whole_ conditions will be evaluated even if the first one returns true for more info about `&` check [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c(v=vs.80).aspx).